# Membership registration limited to list of email addresses

Tags: member-management, guest

We're building a simple site for an event.
Attendees must registrate. But we want to verify if they are on the guest list.

Can we use the normal member registration? Is there an addon for this?
Or is there a better way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a fairly small number of members you could pre-create their accounts with random passwords then create a "registration form" which gets them to reset the password.